# Does spring security support Windows live ID?

Tags: security, authentication, web, spring-security, windows-live-id

for more details about the live id :
https://accountservices.passport.net/ppnetworkhome.srf

I have seen jar files in spring-security-2.0.5 indicating support for

1. acl (i dont knw wht it is)
2. cas (no idea again)
3. NtLm
4. open id

does it support windows live id / is there any extension for spring that supports it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the answer is "no" i guess ?